# PHP: Best way to "explode" string based on regex / find elements between regex maches

Tags: php, regex

Lets say I have a string such as:

```
155+44x3/2-12
```

How can I split it up so that the end result would be:

```
$numbers = [155, 44, 3, 2, 12];
$operators = ['+', 'x', '/', '-'];
```

I can get one or the other separately fairly easily using regex, but is there a good way to get the numbers using regex and then get "the rest" into another variable without writing explicit regex for it? The array items should be correctly ordered as per the initial string.

Or two separate regex clauses would be the best in this case? E.g.

```
preg_match_all($string, "/(\d+)/", $numbers);
preg_match_all($string, "/(\D+)/", $rest);
```

Comment: Are you talking about `preg_match_all("/\d+|\D+/", $string, $numbers);`? Or do you mean you want to get two separate arrays?

Comment: I want to get both of the arrays, with correctly indexed items, but ideally with a single operation/regex

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may be able to do this in a single `preg_match_all` call with 2 capture groups in this regex:

```
(\d+)(\D*)
```

Which matches 1+ digits in capture group #1 and matches 0 or more non-digits in capture group #2

[RegEx Demo](https://regex101.com/r/Jq2wdQ/1)

```php
$s = '155+44x3/2-12';
if (preg_match_all('/(\d+)(\D*)/', $s, $m)) {
   $numbers = $m[1];
   $operators = array_filter($m[2]);
   // print arrays
   print_r($numbers);
   print_r($operators);
}
```

**Output:**

```php
Array
(
    [0] => 155
    [1] => 44
    [2] => 3
    [3] => 2
    [4] => 12
)
Array
(
    [0] => +
    [1] => x
    [2] => /
    [3] => -
)
```

`array_filter` has been used to filter out empty elements from array.

Answer (score 2):

Using two regexes is no sin to be sure, and the `preg_match_all()` of the other answer would also work. Another approach is to capture them into a single array, and then fork it into two. Since we're talking about splitting, let's use [`preg_split()`](http://php.net/preg_split) with the `PREG_SPLIT_DELIM_CAPTURE` flag. That produces a single array of numbers, as below for your sample equation:

```
Array [
  [0] => 155
  [1] => +
  [2] => 44
  [3] => x
  [4] => 3
  [5] => /
  [6] => 2
  [7] => -
  [8] => 12
]
```

Now, since your equation will start with a number, it's a fairly safe assumption that all your operators will have *odd keys* in the resulting array. We can then separate them with `% 2 == 0`, or zero modulo with two, on the key, thereby forking odds and evens into separate arrays.

```
$equation = '155+44x3/2-12';

// Use ~\s*(\D)\s*~ if you may have spaces around operators
// Use ~(?<!\D)(\D)~ with lookbehind if you have negative integers

$splits = preg_split('~(\D)~', $equation, -1, PREG_SPLIT_DELIM_CAPTURE);

$bits = [];

array_walk($splits, function($v, $k) use (&$bits) {
    $type = $k % 2 == 0 ? 'numbers' : 'operators';
    $bits[$type][] = $v;
});
```

This results in:

```
array(2) {
    ["numbers"] · array(5) {
        [0] · string(3) "155"
        [1] · string(2) "44"
        [2] · string(1) "3"
        [3] · string(1) "2"
        [4] · string(2) "12"
    }
    ["operators"] · array(4) {
        [0] · string(1) "+"
        [1] · string(1) "x"
        [2] · string(1) "/"
        [3] · string(1) "-"
    }
}
```

Be aware that a basic regex separating digits from operators will fail if you have `-` signed integers in there. You can add in a negative look-behind that excludes a minus preceded by an operator; and your regex would then look like `~(?<!\D)(\D)~` instead.

You might also have spaces around the operators. In that case, add optional spaces outside the operator capture/split-matcher regex: `~\s*(\D)\s*~` to have spaces discarded in the split while the operator itself is captured.

N.B. *You can't combine* the negative lookbehind for `-` signed numbers with an *optional* space, because negative lookbehinds need to be fixed-length. You either have spaces `(?<!\D\s)` or you don't `(?<!\D)`. This will work: `~\s*(?<!\D\s)(\D)\s*~` for `155 +  44 x 3 / 2 * -12`; and this `~\s*(?<!\D)(\D)\s*~` for splitting `155+44x3/2*-12`.

Further, if your equation uses two-character-operators, like PHP's `**` for power-of, you'll want to revise the regex to match. If you have `(` brackets `)` and other notation included, it's a whole other horse to ride again. This approach should do for the basics though.

Comment: That's a very interesting approach, thanks for the great answer & explanation, appreciate it!

Comment: Sure thing. If you intend to work further and actually use the numbers with functions that expect integers, you'll want to additionally cast whatever goes into "numbers" as `(int)`. By default they are strings, true to their origin, and will throw errors if you're working in type-strict mode (a good idea).